# Remove all punctuation except apostrophes in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, punctuation

I'd like to use R's gsub to remove all punctuation from a text except for apostrophes.  I'm fairly new to regex but am learning.

**Example:**

```
x <- "I like %$@to*&, chew;: gum, but don't like|}{[] bubble@#^)( gum!?"
gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", as.character(x))
```

**Current Output (no apostrophe in don't)**

```
[1] "I like to chew gum but dont like bubble gum"
```

**Desired Output (I desire the apostrophe in don't to stay)**

```
[1] "I like to chew gum but don't like bubble gum"
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
x <- "I like %$@to*&, chew;: gum, but don't like|}{[] bubble@#^)( gum!?"
gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]']", "", x)

[1] "I like to chew gum but don't like bubble gum"
```

The above regex is much more straight forward. It replaces everything that's not alphanumeric signs, space or apostrophe (caret symbol!) with an empty string.

Comment: Kay  your code does remove the apostrophe. This is what I think you meant `gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]'\"]", "", x)`

Comment: I like how straight forward this coding is.

Comment: +1 -- The idea here points to be the clearest possible solution, in my opinion. Just edit the second line to read `gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]']", "", x)` and it's golden. (FWIW, the backslash isn't needed inside the regex).

Comment: of course this answer gets out of whack if your text contains non-ascii characters (e.g. text in multiple scripts)

Answer (score 12):

You can exclude apostrophes from the POSIX class `punct` using a double negative:

```
[^'[:^punct:]]
```

**Code:**

```
x <- "I like %$@to*&, chew;: gum, but don't like|}{[] bubble@#^)( gum!?"
gsub("[^'[:^punct:]]", "", x, perl=T)

#[1] "I like to chew gum but don't like bubble gum"
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/ZBeIH8)</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example:

```
>  gsub("(.*?)($|'|[^[:punct:]]+?)(.*?)", "\\2", x)
[1] "I like to chew gum but don't like bubble gum"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for.  Way more complicated that I thought it would be.  No wonder I was having trouble.  I'll really pull apart what you did.  Thank you.

Comment: Finally this would be the simplest way `gsub(".*?($|'|[^[:punct:]]).*?", "\\1", x)`.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up.  It works as well as the first and is simpler to follow. +1

Answer (score 5):

Mostly for variety, here's a solution using `gsubfn()` from the terrific package of the same name. In this application, I just like how nicely expressive the solution it allows is:

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn(pattern = "[[:punct:]]", engine = "R",
       replacement = function(x) ifelse(x == "'", "'", ""), 
       x)
[1] "I like to chew gum but don't like bubble gum"
```

(The argument `engine = "R"` is needed here as otherwise the default tcl engine will be used. Its rules for matching regular expressions are slightly different: if it were used to process the string above, for instance, one would need to instead set `pattern = "[[:punct:]$|^]"`. Thanks to G. Grothendieck for pointing out that detail.)

Comment: One caveat -- for some reason, the character class `[:punct:]`, when used in the `pattern` argument of a `gsubfn()` call, does not match the characters `$`, `|`, or `^` as it would in a call to `gsub()`. I thus had to add them 'by hand'.

Comment: `gsubfn` uses tcl regular expression by default.  Use the argument `engine = "R"` if you wish to use R regular expressions.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck -- Thanks for pointing that out. I've incorporated it in my answer. I had taken the documentation in `?gsubfn`, which states that `pattern: Same as 'pattern' in 'gsub'`, to mean that the patterns should be specified in the same way. Now I see what was meant by that, but wonder whether an additional line there might help. Something like `If engine="R", character strings will be matched as documented by 'help(regex)'. If the default tcl engine is used, patterns will be matched as documented at ...`. In any case, thanks for your work on the package!