# R regex remove all punctuation except apostrophe

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to remove all punctuation from a string except apostrophes.  Here's my exastr2 <-

```
str2 <- "this doesn't not have an apostrophe,.!@#$%^&*()"
gsub("[[:punct:,^\\']]"," ", str2 )
# [1] "this doesn't not have an apostrophe,.!@#$%^&*()"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm linking the same question with a bad title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697079/regex-exception-in-r

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A "negative lookahead assertion" can be used to remove from consideration any apostrophes, before they are even tested for being punctuation characters.

```
gsub("(?!')[[:punct:]]", "", str2, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "this doesn't not have an apostrophe"
```

Comment: This doesn't remove, of course, if the two apostrophes occur next to each other. But I guess you already knew that.

Comment: FWIW, [here's a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) to the best short explanation of negative lookaround assertions that I've ever seen.

Comment: You can also exclude an apostrophe and i.e., a colon with "(?!')(?!:)[[:punct:]]"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can specify all punctuations except `'` within a regexp the way you've done. I would check for `alphanumerics` + `'` + `space` with negation:

```
gsub("[^'[:lower:] ]", "", str2) # per Joshua's comment
# [1] "this doesn't not have an apostrophe"
```

Comment: It depends what he wants.  Does he want to ensure he only gets letters  then  what you wrote is most appropriate.  If he really just wants to remove punctuation then it is safer to explicitly remove punctuation.

Comment: You should use `[[:lower:]]` instead of `[a-z]` as the latter is locale-specific.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
str2 <- "this doesn't not have an apostrophe,.!@#$%^&*()"

library(qdap)
strip(str2, apostrophe.remove = FALSE, lower.case = FALSE)
```

Comment: Tyler, openNLP a "depends" package doesn't install and exits with warning message "not available for R 2.15.2 and so couldn't install `qdap`. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes check this page out: http://trinker.github.com/qdap_install/installation. I assume you're using a mac.

Comment: Can you let me know if iy works for you or improvements I could make to the install instructions.

Comment: Tyler, from the link, it worked like a charm. No issues.