# R - Detect any punctuation in value except for period

Tags: r, regex

I want to check a column or value for any punctuation except for periods `.`. I've looked at a bunch of the similar questions, but can't seem to get it right.

Desired output:

```
"1.0" FALSE
"-1.0" TRUE
"-1" TRUE
"1+" TRUE
```

Attempts:

```
> grepl("([.])[[:punct:]]", "1.0")
[1] FALSE
> grepl("([.])[[:punct:]]", "-1.0")
[1] FALSE
> grepl("(.)[[:punct:]]", "-1.0")
[1] TRUE
> grepl("(.)[[:punct:]]", "1.0")
[1] TRUE
```

Based R is preferred but required.

Comment: Perhaps remove periods and then use `grepl` with `[[:punct:]]`, e.g., `grepl("[[:punct:]]", gsub("\\.", "", x))`

Comment: @GregorThomas Simple and it works. Should be fast enough on large columns as well

Comment: If you want to speed it up, use `fixed = TRUE` in the `gsub` (see the answer). Using `stringi` package could get you a little more speed.

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude `.` from `[:punct:]` with `(?![.])[[:punct:]]` or `(?!\\.)[[:punct:]]` using a *negative lookahead*,

```
x <- c("1.0", "-1.0", "-1", "1+")
grepl("(?![.])[[:punct:]]", x, perl=TRUE)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

or use double negation, as given in the comments by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1.

```
grepl("[^[:^punct:].]", x, perl=TRUE)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

But being explicit and using for your given example `[-+]`, `[^[:digit:].]` or `[^0-9.]` might be better,

```
grepl("[-+]", x)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

grepl("[^[:digit:].]", x)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

grepl("[^0-9.]", x)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

as *if a locale is in effect, it could alter the behaviour of [[:punct:]]* and changing between `perl=FALSE` and `perl=TRUE` is altering it to.

```
gsub("[^[:punct:]]", "", intToUtf8(c(32:126, 160:255)), perl=FALSE)
#[1] "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©«¬­®¯°±²³´¶·¸¹»¼½¾¿×÷"

gsub("[^[:punct:]]", "", intToUtf8(c(32:126, 160:255)), perl=TRUE)
#[1] "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"
```

See also:
[in R, use gsub to remove all punctuation except period](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21533899/10488504), 
[R regex remove all punctuation except apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15255709/10488504) or
[Remove all punctuation except apostrophes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8697079/10488504).

Answer (score 3):

Make it a two-step process. First remove periods, second detect (remaining) punctuation:

```
grepl("[[:punct:]]", gsub("\\.", "", x))

## use fixed = TRUE for a bit more speed in the gsub
grepl("[[:punct:]]", gsub(".", "", x, fixed = TRUE))
```