# How to remove the last character of a string if it is a punctuation?

Tags: r, regex

It suppose to be very simple. 
For example:

```
a = "fafasdf..", b = "sdfs?>", c = "safwe"
```

The result i want would be

```
a = "fafasdf", b = "sdfs", c = "safwe"
```

How do I remove the last few characters if they are punctuation?
I tried `sub("[:punct:]\Z", "", mystring)`, but it does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX character classes need to be wrapped inside of a bracketed expression, the correct syntax would be `[[:punct:]]`. And, since you're not utilizing `gsub` to remove all instances, you need to specify an [operator](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet) to match more than one occurrence of punctuation.

As commented in the other answer; the `perl = TRUE` parameter needs to be set to use `\Z`.

But for future reference — not to dissuade you, this anchor behaves differently depending on the engine being used; being said in R with the parameter set, this anchor will allow a match before a final line break. However, it's alright to use it here, but I would just stick to `$` instead.

```
sub('[[:punct:]]+$', '', c('fafasdf..', 'sdfs?>', 'safwe'))
## [1] "fafasdf" "sdfs"    "safwe"
```

Also take into account the 'locale', it could affect the behavior of the POSIX class. If this becomes an issue, you can read up on this previously [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348643/r-regex-with-stringi-icu-why-is-a-considered-a-non-punct-character/26348797#26348797) question.

If you're just wanting to removing non-word characters, you could just use:

```
sub('\\W+$', '', c('fafasdf..', 'sdfs?>', 'safwe'))
## [1] "fafasdf" "sdfs"    "safwe"
```

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there,

```
sub("[[:punct:]]+$", "", mystring)
```

You need to put `[:punct:]` inside a character class and make it to repeat one or more times by adding `+` next to that. And also replace `\Z` with `$`, since  sub without `perl=TRUE` param won't support `\Z` (which matches the end of the string boundary)

*Example:*

```
x <- c("fafasdf..", "sdfs?>", "safwe")
sub("[[:punct:]]+$", "", x)
# [1] "fafasdf" "sdfs"    "safwe"
```

If you really want to use `\\Z`, then enable `perl=TRUE` param.

```
sub("[[:punct:]]+\\Z", "", x, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "fafasdf" "sdfs"    "safwe"
```

Comment: I didn't know either until 5 minutes ago :)

Comment: then it must support `\z` also `sub("[[:punct:]]+\\z", "", x, perl=TRUE)`