# Replace second instance of punctuation in string?

Tags: r, regex

Have many strings with the pattern:

A/B/C/D

I just need to change the 2nd '/' to something else (say, *)

So A/B/C/D --> A/B*C/D

```
gsub('(^[[:punct:]])([[:punct:]])', "*", string) #Didn't Work
gsub('[[:punct:]]{2}', "*", string) #Didn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with `sub` to capture one or more characters that are not a `/` followed by a `/` and characers that are not a `/` as a group and in the replacement use the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group with the character `*`

```
sub("^([^/]+[/][^/]+)[/]", "\\1*", str1)
#[1] "A/B*C/D"
```

---

Also, if the string is of fixed length with each letter followed by `/`, then can do an assignment with `substring`

```
substring(str1, 4, 4) <- "*"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'A/B/C/D'
```

Comment: Adding this as the answer as it is the 'cleanest', but Wiktor Stribizew's solution worked as well.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
sub("([^[:punct:]]*[[:punct:]][^[:punct:]]*)[[:punct:]]", "\\1*", string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kG14jV/1)

The `sub` function will find a single (first) occurrence of

- `([^[:punct:]]*[[:punct:]][^[:punct:]]*)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this value from the replacement pattern): 0+ chars other than punctuation symbols, a punctuation symbol and then again 0+ chars other than punctuation symbols
- `[[:punct:]]` - a punctuation symbol.

Alternatively, you may try a similar PCRE regex like

```
sub("\\P{P}*\\p{P}\\P{P}*\\K\\p{P}", "*", string, perl=TRUE)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kG14jV/2).

However, [`\p{P}` does not match what `[[:punct:]]` does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348643/r-regex-with-stringi-icu-why-is-a-considered-a-non-punct-character), so be careful. Or replace all `\p{P}` with `[\p{P}\p{S}]` and all `\P{P}` with `[^\p{P}\p{S}]`.

Comment: The 'sub' solution indeed worked well, the PCRE solution wont work in my exact case but I applaud the solution nonetheless. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use a lookbehind to match `/` that follows the pattern "word character-forward slash-word character":

```
sub("(?<=^\\w/\\w)/", "*", "A/B/C/D", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "A/B*C/D"
```

Similarly, we can also use a lookahead:

```
sub("/(?=\\w/\\w$)", "*", "A/B/C/D", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "A/B*C/D"
```

Of course, we can also use a combination of `[^[:punct:]]` and `[[:punct:]]` to achieve the same result in this case. Be aware though that the following pattern is more general:

```
sub("(?<=^[^[:punct:]][[:punct:]][^[:punct:]])[[:punct:]]", "*", "A/B/C/D", perl = TRUE)
# [1] "A/B*C/D"
```