# R regex trimming a string whitespace

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a string that downloaded from the web:

```
x = "the company 's newly launched cryptocurrency , Libra , hasn 't been contacted by Facebook , according to a report ."
```

They parsed the string such that: ...In addition, contracted words like (can't) are separated into two parts (ca n't) and punctuation is separated from words (eye level . As her).

I want to make the string back to normal, for example:

```
x = "the company's newly launched cryptocurrency, Libra, hasn't been contacted by Facebook, according to a report."
```

How do I trim the space before the punctuation?

Have though about using str_remove_all with regex:

```
str_remove_all(x,"\\s[[:punct:]]'")
```

but it will also remove the punctuation.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess it is before a punctuation it will add a space on the leading side. The reason why they did that is perhaps it is easier to do n-grams but I want the whole word instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With back referencing:

```
x <- "the company 's newly launched cryptocurrency , Libra , hasn 't been contacted by Facebook , according to a report ."

gsub("(\\s+)([[:punct:]])", "\\2", x, perl = TRUE)

# [1] "the company's newly launched cryptocurrency, Libra, hasn't been contacted by Facebook, according to a report."
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
str_remove_all(x,"\\s+(?=[[:punct:]])")
str_remove_all(x,"\\s+(?=[\\p{S}\\p{P}])")
```

Or base  R:

```
gsub("\\s+(?=[\\p{S}\\p{P}])", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y0C1WS/1).

**Details**

- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace chars
- `(?=[[:punct:]])` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a punctuation character.

Please check [R/regex with stringi/ICU: why is a '+' considered a non-[:punct:] character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348643) before choosing the variant with `[[:punct:]]`.

Comment: Sir this is a perfect answer many thanks for your help!