# How do I add a space between two characters using regex in R?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to add a space between two punctuation characters (+ and -).
I have this code:

```
s <- "-+"
str_replace(s, "([:punct:])([:punct:])", "\\1\\s\\2")
```

It does not work.
May I have some help?

Comment: I don't know about R, but with PCRE, for example, you would want `([[:punct:]])([[:punct:]])`. Another way, again with PCRE, would be to replace the (zero-width) match of `(?<=[[:punct:]])(?=[[:punct:]])` with a space (`(?<=[[:punct:]])` being a *negative lookbehind* and `(?=[[:punct:]])` being a *negative lookahead*). [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N1JmjC/1).

Comment: With `stringr` and `stringi`, some punctuations(e.g. `'+'`) cannot be matched by `[:punct:]`. But `sub` from `base` R handles it well. Try `gsub("([[:punct:]])([[:punct:]])", "\\1 \\2", s)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/26348643/10068985

Comment: `str_replace` uses the ICU engine which is different from the PCRE engine used by base R. `[[:punct:]]` is a PCRE support metaclass, and not ICU

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

- `[:punct:]` pattern in an ICU regex flavor does not match math symbols (`\p{S}`), it only matches punctuation proper (`\p{P}`), if you still want to match all of them, combine the two classes, `[\p{P}\p{S}]`
- `"\\1\\s\\2"` replacement contains a `\s` regex escape sequence, and these are not supported in the replacement patterns, you need to use a literal space
- `str_replace` only replaces one, first occurrence, use `str_replace_all` to handle all matches
- Even if you use all the above suggestions, it still won't work for strings like `-+?/`. You need to make the second part of the regex a *zero-width assertion*, a positive lookahead, in order not to consume the second punctuation.

So, you can use

```
library(stringr)
s <- "-+?="
str_replace_all(s, "([\\p{P}\\p{S}])(?=[\\p{P}\\p{S}])", "\\1 ")
str_replace_all(s, "(?<=[\\p{P}\\p{S}])(?=[\\p{P}\\p{S}])", " ")
gsub("(?<=[[:punct:]])(?=[[:punct:]])", " ", s, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/7DVH4x), all three lines yield `[1] "- + ? ="` output.

Note that in PCRE regex flavor (used with `gsub` and `per=TRUE`) the POSIX character class must be put inside a bracket expression, hence the use of double brackets in `[[:punct:]]`.

Also, `(?<=[[:punct:]])` is a positive lookbehind that checks for the presence of its pattern immediately on the left, and since it is non-consuming there is no need of any backreference in the replacement.