# R str_replace_all except periods and dashes

Tags: r, regex, str-replace

I am trying to replace all punctuation and "not words" except for "." and "-" in a string, but am struggling to find the right combination to set up the regex expression.

I've been using the following str_replace_all() code in R, but now I want to specify to ignore "." and "-". I've tried setting it up to include things like [^.-] and ([.-]), but I'm not getting the desired output.

```
str_replace_all("[APPLE/O.ORANGE*PLUM-11]", regex("[\\W+,[:punct:]]", perl=T)," ")

" APPLE O ORANGE PLUM 11 " #current output

" APPLE O.ORANGE PLUM-11 " #desired output
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Error: could not find function "str_replace_all". You should specify which packages you use when asking about non-base R functions.

Comment: See the [in R, use gsub to remove all punctuation except period](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60514641/3832970) answer with correct solutions. The currently accepted `[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]` will remove a lot of Unicode letters and numbers, not just punctuation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably easier to use the ^, which means that it is matching everything not referenced within the brackets. By including all letters, numbers, ., and - in the box you don't replace those.

```
library(stringr) 
str_replace_all("[APPLE/O.ORANGE*PLUM-11]", "[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]"," ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `str_replace_all` does not allow using PCRE patterns, the [*stringr* library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf) is ICU regex powered.

What you need to do can be done with a base R `gsub` using the following pattern:

```
> x<-"[APPLE/O.ORANGE*PLUM-11]"
> gsub("[^\\w.-]", " ", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] " APPLE O.ORANGE PLUM-11 "
```

See the [R demo online](http://ideone.com/GGCOhh). Also, see the [regex online demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Egahlm/1).

The `[^\\w.-]` pattern matches any character other than (since `[^...]` is a negated character class) word char (letter, digit, `_`), `.` and `-`.