# Postgresql invalid class for [:^punct]

Tags: node.js, regex, postgresql, posix

Having read the answer in the [Remove all punctuation except apostrophes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33061764/8596380) post, I tried to use

```
'[[:space:]]|[^\/[:^punct:]]'
```

in REGEXP_REPLACE function, but it gives me

```
[2201B] ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid character class
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: What are you trying to match? Any whitespace or any punctuation but `/`?

Comment: I'm trying to match a string that contains alphanumeric plus danish characters plus / , the regex is used in REGEXP_REPLACE(ref,'[[:space:]]|[^\/[:^punct:]]','','g');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you link to is tagged with [r](/questions/tagged/r), where `stringr` library uses ICU regex flavor that supports POSIX character classes in its own way, not necessarily POSIX compatible.

To match any whitespace or any punctuation but `/` you may use

```
[^/[:alnum:]]
```

It matches any char that is not alphanumeric (and that means it is either a whitespace or punctuation) and not a `/` char.

Comment: I also need to include danish characters

Comment: @MedAmine Does it mean you want to remove Danish characters? Do you have a list of those you want to remove? Just put them after `/`.

Comment: @MedAmine FYI, you may use `'[^/A-Z0-9]+'` if you want to remove all letters but ASCII letters & digits & `/` char.