# How to remove punctuation excluding negations?

Tags: r, regex, stringr, punctuation

Let's assume I have the following sentence:

```
s = c("I don't want to remove punctuation for negations. Instead, I want to remove only general punctuation. For example, keep I wouldn't like it but remove Inter's fan or Man city's fan.")
```

I would like to have the following outcome:

```
"I don't want to remove punctuation for negations Instead I want to remove only general punctuation For example keep I wouldn't like it but remove Inter fan or Man city fan."
```

At the moment if I simply use the code below, I remove both 's and ' in the negations.

```
  s %>%  str_replace_all("['']s\\b|[^[:alnum:][:blank:]@_]"," ")

 "I don t want to remove punctuation for negations  Instead  I want to remove only general punctuation           For example  keep I wouldn t like it but remove Inter  fan or Man city  fan "
```

To sum up, I need to have a code that removes general punctuation, including "'s" except for negations that I want to keep in their raw format.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks!

Comment: Negation is always(?) `"'t"`, maybe just remove `"'s"` with a fixed match?

Comment: The issue with that is that I still need to clear the general punctuation. Whichever cleaning strategy I used so far removed `"'t"`

Comment: Then do it with 2 steps, [remove all punctuation excluding "'"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8698368/680068), then remove "'s" using fixed match.

Comment: Why the full stop "." is not removed at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it in two steps, [remove all punctuation excluding `"'"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8697079/680068), then remove `"'s"` using fixed match:

```
gsub("'s", "", gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]']", "", s), fixed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a look ahead `(?!t)` testing that the `[:punct:]` is not followed by a `t`.

```
gsub("[[:punct:]](?!t)\\w?", "", s, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "I don't want to remove punctuation for negations Instead I want to remove only general punctuation For example keep I wouldn't like it but remove Inter fan or Man city fan"
```

In case you want to be more strict you can test in addition if there is no `n` before with `(?<!n)`.

```
gsub("(?<!n)[[:punct:]](?!t)\\w?", "", s, perl=TRUE)
```

Or in case to restrict it only to `'t` (thanks to @chris-ruehlemann)

```
gsub("(?!'t)[[:punct:]]\\w?", "", s, perl=TRUE)
```

Or remove every `punct` but not `'` or `'s`:

```
gsub("[^'[:^punct:]]|'s", "", s, perl = TRUE)
```

The same but use look ahead:

```
gsub("(?!')[[:punct:]]|'s", "", s, perl = TRUE)
```